# php json_encode how to use " " instead of "+" in text strings?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I encode array of objects to cookie in JS:

```
prod.name = name;
prod.id = id;
prod.price = cost;
prod.quantity = 1;
Products = [prod];
Cookies.set('cart', Products);
```

And name looks like `"Some product name"`, but when i'm doing same thing from PHP:

```
setcookie('products', json_encode($Products));
```

I got name like "Some+product+name" - is there any way to avoid it, or the only way is to `str_replace() + with " "` (what is unicode analog for theme)?

UPD. To be simple:

If I `setcookie ('cartNew', json_encode(['name' => "Some product name"]));` - in cookie I see "+", and JS decode that as "+". Cookie is like `%7B%22name%22%3A%22Some+product+name%22%7D` - firefox. Also I use UTF-8, and php 5.4

Comment: can you put your json encoded data here in your code. thanks.

Comment: And please put `$Products` value. thanks

Comment: *"I got name like "Some+product+name" "* "Got" it ***how***? Cookies are URI-encoded. Whatever you're using to "get" it will need to *decode* it.

Comment: Please put your `$Products` value here in your code for solution. thanks.

Comment: @frenzy It's not really a good idea to store data in a cookie. The best approach is to store a session id in the cookie and then store the data on the server side bound on that ID. When that is said it would properly also make more sense to store the cart's in a database and only store the cart id in the server session storage.

Comment: `json_encode(['name' => "Some product name"])` does ***not*** result in any `+` characters...

Comment: Yep, but only if you do everything on serverside. If you setcookie  ('cartNew', json_encode(['name' => "Some product name"])); - in cookie I see "+"(%7B%22name%22%3A%22Some+product+name%22%7D), and JS decode that as "+". Also I use UTF-8 - no ascii.

Comment: ??!?!?! `json_encode` does not add any `+`, period. They are being added somewhere else in whatever process you put your data through (PHP → output over HTTP → Javascript → Cookies → HTTP again). Focusing your question on `json_encode` is nonsense, because it is most certainly not the culprit. And we do not know enough about the rest of the data flow to tell you where the problem is.

Comment: @deceze see my UPD. Maybe it setcookie.

Answer (score -1):

Use a RegEx replace to get rid of the the extra '+'s:

`prod.name = name.replace(/\+/g, "");`

Comment: Don't fix the problem after the fact. Figure out where the `+`s are coming from in the first place and get rid of them there. Something's being en-/decoded in the wrong order here, that's the real issue.

Comment: PHP json_encode replaces " " with "+", not adding new